# What exactly does the prefix 'in-' signify, in 'impartire'?

Tags: etymology, prefix

It seems that the Latin verb [*impartire*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dimpartio) (more commonly [*impertire*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=impertio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)) means "to share with another, to communicate, bestow, impart".
The English verb [*impart*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=impart&searchmode=none) comes from this.

What does the prefix *in-* mean here?
It usually means "into" or "in", but that doesn't seem to make sense with this word.
Surely it can't mean dividing communication into smaller pieces.

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your question to focus more on Latin?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Not at all! As always, please edit my questions to improve them.

Comment: I edited it and voted up. The etymology of the English word not very important for the question about Latin, so I only included a link. Long quotes distract, especially now that the question was not about all of it. I added links to a Latin dictionary for the relevant words. The question is about Latin, so a Latin dictionary is important to consult.

Answer (score 2):

*Partire in tria* means to divide **into** three things. This idiomatic use of *in* is, perhaps, the reason it was prefixed to *partire* to make *impertire*. When you impart something, you are dividing it into things, whether three things, or two things, or twenty things, for the purpose of divvying it up. If the particular number of things is not what's important, there is no reason to spell it out. You just need to prefix *in* to your verb and get on with saying what's really important.

Comment: This reminds me of how Gaul was *divisa in partes tres*. A famously attested idiom.

Comment: Quite different from the meaning of *in-* in *indivisus*.  :)